# Differential geometry and tensors using Cartan method: advantages over other methods in Physics?

Tags: differential-geometry

Let me begin with a simple example. I am trying to calculate the Christoffel symbols, the Ricci and the Curvature tensor for the metric of the surface (parabolic-like):

$ds^2=(1+u^2)du^2+u^2d\theta$

with differential form techniques in order to circularly absorb them and check my previous calculatios (3 non-null Christoffel symbols up to symmetry consideratios). Indeed, I have already made the computations of those quantities using tensor calculus and the lagrangian trick, but I am not able to compute the quantities using the Cartan approach...I begin defining

$e_1=\sqrt{1+u^2}du$

$e_2=ud\theta$

$e=\begin{pmatrix} e_1\\ e_2\end{pmatrix}$

$de=\begin{pmatrix} 0\\ du\wedge d\theta\end{pmatrix}$

$de=\omega\wedge e=\begin{pmatrix}0 & \dfrac{-1}{\sqrt{1+u^2}}d\theta\\
\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1+u^2}}d\theta & 0\end{pmatrix}\wedge\begin{pmatrix} -\sqrt{1+u^2}du\\ -ud\theta\end{pmatrix}$

Since we are considering a parabolic surface 2d embedded in 3d, $\omega\wedge\omega=0$ and $\Omega=d\omega$, so

$\Omega=d\omega=\begin{pmatrix}0 & \dfrac{udu\wedge d\theta}{1+u^2}\\
- \dfrac{udu\wedge d\theta}{1+u^2} & 0\end{pmatrix}$

And here is where I don't get the Christoffel symbols correctly...From the lagrangian approach, I obtained $\Gamma^{u}_{uu}=\dfrac{u}{u^2+1}$, $\Gamma^{u}_{\theta\theta}=-\dfrac{u}{u^2+1}$ and $\Gamma^{\theta}_{u\theta}=1/u$.

However, I can NOT see how to read them from the Cartan forms above...Any help? I do know how the Christoffel symbols arise from the covariant derivate, but I don't see how to read off all from the Cartan matrices...I find one of the connection components hard to get it from above calculations ($\Gamma^u_{uu}$)...And what about $R$ and the remaining tensor quantities, like the Ricci or the curvature tensor, the Ricci scalar (any trick related to the determinants of these matrices?), the Weyl tensor, the Einstein tensor, the gaussian curvature...?

Tensor calculus is better of worse for these calculations? I found it more straightforward that Cartan calculus, but I am VERY aware of the effective and practical computations using the Cartan method. How to decide what is better? Are there any rules to decide when is faster one method or another?

Comment: This question seems to be *primarily opinion-based* - what method is "easier" depends on personal taste and practice.

Comment: Sometimes, people say that differential forms are more efficient and less time consuming, but why???